# What timezone does MySQL's NOW() follow

Tags: sql, mysql

Does MySQL's NOW() follow the system's timezone or some standard like GMT or UTC?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's in the current time zone. From the [5.1 docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now):

> Returns the current date and time as a
>   value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or
>   YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format,
>   depending on whether the function is
>   used in a string or numeric context.
>   The value is expressed in the current
>   time zone.

Now "the current time zone" can mean different things:

- The system time zone
- A time zone specified for the MySQL server in general
- A connection-specific time zone

More details are in the [5.1 time zone documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html).

(The 5.4 docs look the same for these bits. Obviously consult the docs for the version you're running for the best possible information.)

Answer (score 24):

Per [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html), the rules are complicated, but mostly boil down to "current session's timezone" (which defaults to system timezone):

> The current session time zone setting
>   affects display and storage of time
>   values that are zone-sensitive. This
>   includes the values displayed by
>   functions such as NOW() or CURTIME(),
>   and values stored in and retrieved
>   from TIMESTAMP columns. Values for
>   TIMESTAMP columns are converted from
>   the current time zone to UTC for
>   storage, and from UTC to the current
>   time zone for retrieval.

Of course you can use `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` if you need UTC specifically.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know its the system clock is returned. Check for your system's time zone. I you connect MySQL locally (like from PHP) time zones will not matter for MySQL, I prefer handling them in PHP.

Comment: Could you explain about the PHP stuff again. If I fetch a timestamp column using PHP what timezone is it in? Default PHP timezone?