# Current time + 12 hours

Tags: php

Hello I have a vote system.

Once a person votes, I have column named "nextVote".

That column will hold the date when the user can vote again.
By that column, I will be able to echo how many hours/minutes he needs to wait before voting.

That's my try:

```
    public final function setNextVote($ip)
    {
        $this->insert = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE auths SET nextVote = NOW() + INTERVAL 12 HOUR WHERE voter_ip = :ip");
        $this->insert->execute(array(":ip" => $ip));
    }
```

And that what it stores:

```
2013-05-14 05:56:24
```

Why?..

What I am trying to do is: Current time + 12 hours.

If today is 2013, 05, 14 and 12:00.

In 12 hours it would be

2013, 05, 14, 24:00
Why doesn't it do that?

```
    public function getTimeLeft($ip)
    {
        $this->get = $this->pdo->prepare
        ("
            SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, `nextVote`, NOW())
            FROM auths
            WHERE `voter_ip` = :ip
        ");
        $echo = $this->get->execute(array(":ip" => $ip));

        return $echo;
    }
```

Comment: You mean in 12 hours it would be 2013-05-15 00:00:00?

Comment: It uses UNIX time which is GMT. It is currently 06:02 PM in the GMT timezone. By adding 12 hours to that, it becomes 06:02 AM, which is what your result indicates.

Comment: no such thing as 24:00, it'd be `2013-05-15 00:00:00`

Comment: run in sql-manager `SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 12 HOUR`

Comment: Even better, run `SELECT NOW()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database looks to be using GMT, you can change the timezone on the database, but that can be difficult on a production machine if other things are using it. It should fix the problem tho. Or, try this

```
$date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( 'now +12 hours' ) );
$sql = "UPDATE auths SET nextVote = '{$date}' WHERE voter_ip = :ip";
```

if you want to update your timezone ( and are on ubuntu ), run `dkpg-reconfigure tzdata`

Comment: Can I use something else than NOW() ?

Comment: you could use php's date function

Comment: Thanks, it worked mate. Any idea how can I now return minutes? For example (CURRENT DATE - nextVote) and then get the minutes/hours: You can vote again in: 5 hours, 03 minutes?

Comment: ^ Look in my updated post to see my method, but it always returns '1'.

Comment: lol again, id use php there, personal preference, but take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906686/php-time-remaining-until-specific-time-from-current-time-of-page-load

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are expecting a result in the local timezone. MySQL uses the system timezone by default to produce a timestamp when calling `NOW()` or any other time/date related functions.

You can change the timezone on the server by passing the `--timezone` parameter to MySQL as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html).

However, the timezone is not relevant for your application, because you're only interested in relative time. Users of your application could possibly be in any timezone, so there's no point to assuming a specific one.

Comment: incorrect. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445702/what-timezone-does-mysqls-now-follow. `NOW()` follows the system's timezone

Comment: @Ascherer You are correct! I just changed my answer, sorry :)

Comment: You are still saying it uses GMT by default, but it doesnt. it uses the systems timezone by default. Also, its a bad assumption to assume the OP has users from multiple timezones

Comment: @Ascherer I think it is a very reasonable assumption, because public applications are much more common than specific internal solutions where the timezone is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the next date to be on the day's boundary... As opposed to 12 hours *from now to the minute* -- you can wrap a `DATE()` around your date math result, which will trim it to just the date for a datetime field.

```
UPDATE auths SET nextVote = DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) WHERE voter_ip = :ip
```